# Using GraphData to generate all directed graphs with n vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

Using Combinatorica, it was possible to generate unlabeled (non-isomorphic) directed graphs of $|V|=n$. Here the example is for $n=4$:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
ShowGraph /@ ListGraphs[4,Directed];
```

Using GraphData, I know how to generate **undirected** ones:

```
GraphData /@ GraphData[4]
```

What's the trick to make it generate directed ones?

Bonus point for directed and **connected** ones.

Comment: With 'directed ones' you mean replacing all `UndirectedEdge`-s with `DirectedEdge`-s?.

Comment: No actually the number of directed graphs with `n` nodes is larger than the undirected graphs with the same number of nodes. Just compare `ShowGraph /@ ListGraphs[4,Directed];` with `ShowGraph /@ ListGraphs[4];`

Comment: Yeah but for n edges there are 2^n choices for directing. Maybe some things become isomorphic to others but still it should give that enlarged set.

Comment: Keep in mind that `GraphData` is just a database of graphs.  It's not exhaustive, and it doesn't generate graphs.  It just looks up the database entries.

Answer (score 8):

## Directed, Connected Graphs of n vertices

First let's find the **un**directed graphs of n vertices. We're only considering those graphs having a single weakly-connected component.

```
connectedUndirectedGraphs[n_]:=Module[{graphs},graphs=GraphData/@GraphData[n];
   Cases[graphs,x_/; Length@WeaklyConnectedComponents[x]==1]]
```

**example**

```
connectedUndirectedGraphs[4]
```

[image: 4 vertices]

---

This imposes a direction on an (undirected) edge. The direction depends on the value of 'bool`.

```
directTheEdge[a_<->b_,bool_]:=If[bool==1,b\[DirectedEdge]a,a\[DirectedEdge]b]
```

(* The following finds all the combinations of directed edges for a set of undirected edges *)

```
directedEdges[unDirectedEdges_]:=
Thread[directTheEdge[unDirectedEdges,#]]&/@Tuples[{0,1},Length[unDirectedEdges]]
```

**example**:

```
directedEdges[{1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}]
```

[image: deges]

---

Display the directed graphs that can be produced from a single undirected graph.
Isomorphism check based on kguler's approach.

```
displayDirectedGraphs[unDirectedGraph_]:=
Module[{el,d},el=EdgeList[unDirectedGraph];d=directedEdges[el];
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Graph[#,
EdgeShapeFunction->GraphElementData[{"HalfFilledArrow","ArrowSize"->.18}],
VertexLabels->"Name"]&/@d],IsomorphicGraphQ]]
```

---

Show all the directed, connected graphs with 3 vertices:

```
displayDirectedGraphs /@ connectedUndirectedGraphs[3]
```

[image: three]

---

```
displayDirectedGraphs /@ connectedUndirectedGraphs[4]
```

[image: four]

Comment: Nice. One minor but important point: `GraphData["Connected", n]` only gives a complete list of all non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ vertices for $1\leq n \leq 7$, and thus this fails when $n\geq 8$. Of course, there are [a lot of graphs](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) when $n$ gets that large (11,117 with $n=8$ and 261,080 when $n=9$), so this limitation is sort of to be expected.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that limitation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

We can get connected undirected graphs on four vertices using

```
c4 = GraphData["Connected", 4];
```

Names and images:

```
Row[Column[GraphData[#, {"StandardName", "Image"}]] & /@ c4, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Define a function that gives all (**non-isomorphic**) directed graphs when input a list of edges:

```
ClearAll[dgF];
dgF[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{el = #, tpls = Tuples[{Identity, Reverse}, Length@#]},
    DeleteDuplicates[Graph[MapThread[Thread[#[#2]] &, {#, el}], opts] & /@ tpls,
                     IsomorphicGraphQ]] &;
```

and set some options:

```
options = {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .3, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction->GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize"->.1, "ArrowPositions" ->.75}]};
```

Combining all into a function that takes an integer and options as arguments (as suggested by David):

```
graphsF[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] :=
 Module[{c = GraphData[#, {"Name", "Image", "EdgeRules"}] & /@ GraphData["Connected", n]}, 
  Grid[{Rotate[Style[#1, "Panel", 14], Pi/2],Magnify[#2, .5], ## & @@ dgF[opts][#3]} & @@@ c, 
        Dividers -> {{True, True, {False}, True}, All}]]

graphsF[4, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range[4] -> Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]], ## & @@ options]
```

[image]

```
graphsF[3, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range[3]->{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], ## & @@ options]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice use of graph names, "Connected", and isomorphism.

Comment: A generalization of your method for labeling: `graphs[n_] :=
 Module[{c, cb},
  c = GraphData["Connected", n];
  cb = GraphData[#, "EdgeRules"] & /@ c;
  Row[Column[GraphData[#, {"StandardName", "Image"}]] & /@ c, 
   Spacer[10]]]`

Answer (score 3):

The following is by far the most efficient solution (let me know if you know a better one).

---

You can use the `geng` tools from [the nauty suite](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) to generate non-isomorphic undirected graphs with various constraints. The `directg` tool can take un undirected graph as input, and generate all non-isomorphic directed ones by orienting its edges as `->`, `<-` or `<->`.

These tools use the Graph6, Digraph6 and Sparse6 format for interchanging graphs. Mathematica has built-in support for Graph6 and Sparse6, but not for Digraph6. The [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM adds support for Digraph6 and improves the import performance for Graph6 and Sparse6.

Assuming that the nauty suite is installed and in your path, you can do the following:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
```

Generate all unlabelled directed graphs on 4 vertices, and count them:

```
IGImport["!geng 4 | directg", "Nauty"] // Length
(* 218 *)
```

The same on 5 vertices:

```
IGImport["!geng 5 | directg", "Nauty"] // Length
(* 9608 *)
```

Count how many are strongly connected. The `-c` option of `geng` generates only connected undirected graphs, which reduces the number of graphs that we need to import into Mathematica for further processing, and improves performance:

```
IGImport["!geng -c 5 | directg", "Nauty"] // Select[ConnectedGraphQ] // Length
(* 5048 *)
```

Orient each edge in only one direction (`-o`) and select strongly connected graphs:

```
IGImport["!geng -c 4 | directg -o", "Nauty"] // Select[ConnectedGraphQ]
```

[image]

Pre-filtering using the options of `geng` and `directg` can vastly improve performance. This takes only 1.6 seconds on my machine:

```
IGImport["!geng -c 6 | directg -o", "Nauty"] // Select[ConnectedGraphQ] // Length
(* 4232 *)
```

In total, [there are 1.5 million directed graphs on 6 vertices](https://oeis.org/A000273), which would take much longer to import.