# Reproducing Graph functionality from Combinatorica using GraphData (ListGraphs, NumberOfGraphs)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to generate graphs with `n` vertices and `e` edges, and I also want the ability to count the number of non-isomorphic graphs with `n` and `e`. I was delighted to find these functions already implemented in Combinatorica as `ListGraphs` and `NumberOfGraphs`. Is there a modern equivalent that uses `GraphData`?

It's unfortunate that, although Combinatorica has been phased out as obsolete, some of its functionality hasn't yet been implemented in mainstream Mathematica. I tried using Combinatorica directly, but I always run into compatibility issues. As an alternative, then, is there a way to just make the old functionality work in modern Mathematica?

Comment: Use `geng`, as I show here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73480/12